# Extending a finite measure from a semi-ring $\mathcal{E}$ to $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $\mathcal{E}$ be a semi-ring of subsets of $\Omega$ and let $\mu:\mathcal{E}\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be a measure on $\mathcal{E}.$

Define the outer measure $\mu^{*}$ generated by the measure $\mu$ via the formula
$$\mu^{*}(A):=\inf \left\{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mu\left(A_{n}\right):\left\{A_{n}\right\} \subset \mathcal{E} \text { and } A \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} A_{n}\right\}.$$
Say that a set $A\in \mathcal {P}(\Omega)$ is $\mu^{*}$-measurable if $\mu^{*}(S)=\mu^{*}(S \cap A)+\mu^{*}\left(S \cap A^{c}\right)$ for each subset $S$ of $\Omega$.
Then:

1. $\mu^{*}(A)=\mu(A)$ for every $A$ belonging to the semi-ring $\mathcal{E}$.
2. The collection $\mathcal{U}_{\mu^{*}}$ of $\mu^{*}$-measurable subsets of $\Omega$ is a $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$, and $\mu^{*}$ is a measure when restricted to $\mathcal{U}_{\mu^{*}}$.
3. If $\mu$ is **$\sigma$-finite** and $\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Omega_{i},\Omega_{i}\in\mathcal{E}$ , then $\mu^{*}$ is the unique
   extension of $\mu$ to a **$\sigma$-finite** measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$.

---

If $\mu$ is **finite** and $\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Omega_{i},\Omega_{i}\in\mathcal{E}$, Is $\mu^{*}$ the extension of $\mu$ to a **finite** measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$?

Since $\sigma(\mathcal{E})$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, $\mu^{*}$ is a finite measure on $\sigma(\mathcal{E})\Leftrightarrow  \mu^{*}(\Omega)<\infty.$ But how to prove  $\mu^{*}(\Omega)<\infty$ under $\mu$ is finite and $\Omega=\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} \Omega_{i},\Omega_{i}\in\mathcal{E}?$

Comment: If you mean $\mu(E)<\infty$ for each $E\in\mathcal E$, a counterexample is the Lebesgue measure on the semi-ring $\{(a,b]: a,b\in\mathbb R\}$.

Comment: It I false that the extension $\mu^*$ of $\mu$ is necessarily a $\sigma$-finite measure unless $\Omega$ can be covered vy countable elements of the smearing.